# Managing services started on boot (rc0.d, rc1.d, etc)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, init.d

What is the best way of managing which services start when?

`service --status-all` lists all services, but does a poor job of the service status (most are "unknown") and does not provide any method of disabling/enabling services.

I read that modifying/deleting the symlinks in the rc*.d folders is not advised, because they can be recreated when their package is upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`service --status-all` is for [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/). If you are using traditional SysV init script, take a look at [sysv-rc-conf](http://sysv-rc-conf.sourceforge.net/) or install `rcconf`.

Comment: Does rcconf work for both upstart and sysv? or do I need two tools to manage all the services, because on Ubuntu 10.04 services seem to be a mix of the two.

Comment: I haven't got a Ubuntu in front of me to test, but `rcconf` seems is only for SysV.